# Computing the $2^\text{nd}$ fundamental form of $\mathbb{R}_+\times M^n\to \mathbb{R}^{n+p+1}$

Tags: riemannian-geometry, submanifold

> Let $f: M^n\to \mathbb{S}^{n+p}$ be an isometric immersion. The *cone* over $f$ is defined to be the immersion
>   \begin{align*}
> F:\mathbb{R}_+\times M &\to \mathbb{R}^{n+p+1}\\
> (t,x)&\mapsto tf(x)
> \end{align*}
>   Compute the second fundamental form of $F$.
>
> [where $\mathbb{R}_+:=\{t\in\mathbb{R}\mid t>0\}$]

I could verify that $F$ is an immersion by considering $f(x)=(f_1(x),...,f_{n+p+1}(x))\in\mathbb{R}^{n+p+1}$ with $\sum_if_i^2=1$. That way, $\langle\frac{\partial f}{\partial x_i},f\rangle=0$ for all $i$ and, since $f$ is an immersion, we have $\frac{\partial f}{\partial x_1},...,\frac{\partial f}{\partial x_n}$ linearly  independent, so $\text{rank}(dF)=\text{rank}\left(f,\frac{\partial f}{\partial x_1},...,\frac{\partial f}{\partial x_n}\right)=n+1$.

For the $2^\text{nd}$ fundamental form, here's where I'm at: If $\widetilde{\nabla}$, $\nabla$ are Levi-Civita connections for $\mathbb{R}^{n+p+1}$ and $\mathbb{R}_+\times M$ respectively, the second fundamental form is by definition $\alpha(X,Y)=\widetilde{\nabla}_\widetilde{X}\widetilde{Y}-\nabla_XY$. By tensoriality and symmetry of $\alpha$, we only need to compute $\alpha\left(\frac{\partial}{\partial t},\frac{\partial}{\partial t}\right),\alpha\left(\frac{\partial}{\partial t},\frac{\partial}{\partial x_i}\right)$ and $\alpha\left(\frac{\partial}{\partial x_i},\frac{\partial}{\partial x_j}\right)$.

To compute $\alpha\left(\frac{\partial}{\partial t},\frac{\partial}{\partial t}\right)$ for example, can see that $\nabla_{\frac{\partial}{\partial t}}\frac{\partial}{\partial t}=0$, but I don't know how compute $\widetilde{\nabla}_{\frac{\partial F}{\partial t}}\frac{\partial F}{\partial t}$. Obviously, $\frac{\partial F}{\partial t}(t,x)=f(x)$, but I can't figure out what $\widetilde{\nabla}_{f(x)}f(x)$ even means.

Any suggestions?

Comment: I wonder why this question received so little attention... is it because it's way too easy, way too hard or way too uninteresting?

Comment: This is a very interesting question, but it exhibits a few technical and conceptual difficulties, and the experts who can help seem to be busy with other things. A couple of remarks: 1) $\widetilde{\nabla}$ should be the standard Euclidean connection (all Christoffels vahish); 2) the expression $\widetilde{\nabla}_{\frac{\partial F}{\partial t}}\frac{\partial F}{\partial t}$ does not make sense. You would rather try to compute $\widetilde{\nabla}_{\frac{\partial}{\partial t}}\frac{\partial}{\partial t}$ (without $F$) etc.

Comment: In fact, I would start with trying to understand the simplest possible case just to see how the answer could look like. So, what would be the answer in the case of $M = \mathbb{S}^{1}$, and $p = n = 1$. where $f$ is the canonical immersion $ \mathbb{S}^{1} \to  \mathbb{S}^{2}$ (as the equator)? The next step would be to figure out what is gonna happen when the immersion varies. After that it should become more clear, how this generalizes to higher dimensions.

Comment: @YuriVyatkin, I'm confused with the expression $\widetilde{\nabla}_{\frac{\partial}{\partial t}}\frac{\partial}{\partial t}$. As I understand it, $\frac{\partial}{\partial t}$ makes sense in $\mathbb{R}_+$, but to see it as in $\mathbb{R}^{n+p+1}$ we need to consider the immersion $F$, right? That's why I thought $\frac{\partial F}{\partial t}=dF\left(\frac{\partial}{\partial t}\right)$ was correct

Comment: Now that you said it, I agree $\widetilde{\nabla}_{\frac{\partial F}{\partial t}}\frac{\partial F}{\partial t}$ isn't really correct, because $\frac{\partial F}{\partial t}$ does not define a vector field in $\mathbb{R}^{n+p+1}$. But if I took some vector field $X$ in $\mathbb{R}^{n+p+1}$ such that $X_{F(t,x)}=\frac{\partial F}{\partial t}(t,x)$ for all $(t,x)$, then $\alpha\left(\frac{\partial}{\partial t},\frac{\partial}{\partial t}\right)=\widetilde{\nabla}_XX-\nabla_{\frac{\partial}{\partial t}}\frac{\partial}{\partial t}$ would make sense, wouldn't it?

Comment: I posted my incomplete answer to show you the picture, from which using some imagination one can see that $\frac{\partial F}{\partial t}$ is a vector field along the cone. So, basically, you are on the right track, just the nature of the things has to be understood more clearly. Sorry, I don't have much time to finish this up, but I will do my best.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The question is purely local, so we may choose a coordinate chart $\varphi \colon U \subset \mathbb{R}^n \to M$ around some point $x \in M$. We use this chart to indentify points in $U$ and $\varphi(U)$, and thus we regard $f$ locally as $\varphi \circ f$, so that the mapping $f \colon U \to \mathbb{R}^{n+p+1}$ is a parametrization of its image, and
$$
\langle f, f \rangle = 1
$$

The mapping
$F \colon \mathbb{R}_{+} \times U \to \mathbb{R}^{n+p+1} \colon (t, x) \mapsto t f(x)$
is also a local parametrization of its image, which is a piece of the cone $C = F(\mathbb{R}_{+} \times U)$.

We calculate at the point $(t, x) \in C$.

Here is a picture showing schematically what is going on:

[image]

Corresponding to the chart $\varphi$, there are local coordinates $x^i$ in $U$, and let $t$ be a local coordinate in $\mathbb{R}_{+}$, so that $\{ t, x^i, i=1, \dots, n \}$ form a coordinate system on $\mathbb{R}_{+} \times U$.

Let us introduce the following notation: $\partial_i := \frac{\partial}{\partial x^i}$, $\partial_t := \frac{\partial}{\partial x^i}$, $f_i := \partial_i f$, $F_i := \partial_i F$, $F_t := \partial_t F$, $i = 1, \dots, n$. Since $F = t f$, we have:
$$
F_i = tf_i \text{ and }F_t = f
$$
Notice that $F_i$ and $F_t$ are vector fields along the cone $C$, and
$$
F_i|_{(t,x)} = t \pmatrix{
f^1_i(x)\\
\vdots\\
f^{n+p+1}_i(x)
}
\text{ and }
F_t|_{(t,x)} = \pmatrix{
f^1(x)\\
\vdots\\
f^{n+p+1}(x)
}
$$

In order to differentiate $F_i$ and $F_t$ in $\mathbb{R}^{n+p+1}$ we need some local coordinates there and some extensions $\widetilde{F}_i$ and $\widetilde{F}_t$ of those fields, so we just take the slice coordinates in $\mathbb{R}_{+} \times U \times \mathbb{R}^{p}$
$$
y^0 = t, y^1 = x^1, \dots, y^n = x^n, y^{n+1} = y^{n+1}, \dots, y^{n+p} = y^{n+p}
$$
(where $y^{n+1}, \dots, y^{n+p}$ are the standard coordinates in $\mathbb{R}^{p}$), and define
$$
\widetilde{F}(t, x^1, \dots, x^n, *, \dots, *) := F(t, x^1, \dots, x^n)
$$
so that $\widetilde{F}_i = \partial_i \widetilde{F}$ and $\widetilde{F}_t = \partial_i \widetilde{F}$.
Since in $\mathbb{R}^{n+p+1}$ we have the standard Euclidean metric and the standard Euclidean connection (all Christoffel symbols vanish identically),
we have
$$
\widetilde{\nabla}_i \widetilde{F}_j = \partial_i F_j \\
\widetilde{\nabla}_t \widetilde{F}_i = \partial_t F_i \\
\widetilde{\nabla}_t \widetilde{F}_t = \partial_t F_t
$$

In order to compute the s.f.f. $\alpha(X,Y)=\widetilde{\nabla}_\widetilde{X}\widetilde{Y}-\nabla_XY$ it remains to understand what $\nabla_XY$ is here.

It is known that $\nabla_XY = (\widetilde{\nabla}_\widetilde{X}\widetilde{Y})^{\top} = \Pi(\widetilde{\nabla}_\widetilde{X}\widetilde{Y})$, where the *tangential projection operator* is given by
$$
\Pi \colon v \mapsto \frac{1}{|F_t|^2} \langle v, F_t \rangle F_t + \sum_{i=1}^{n} \frac{1}{|F_i|^2} \langle v, F_i \rangle F_i
$$
This is almost it, because now we can write
$$
\nabla_i F_j = \Pi(\widetilde{\nabla}_i \widetilde{F}_j) = \frac{1}{|F_t|^2} \langle \widetilde{\nabla}_i \widetilde{F}_j, F_t \rangle F_t + \sum_{k=1}^{n} \frac{1}{|F_k|^2} \langle \widetilde{\nabla}_i \widetilde{F}_j, F_k \rangle F_k \\
\nabla_t F_i = \Pi(\widetilde{\nabla}_t \widetilde{F}_i) = \frac{1}{|F_t|^2} \langle \widetilde{\nabla}_t \widetilde{F}_i, F_t \rangle F_t + \sum_{k=1}^{n} \frac{1}{|F_k|^2} \langle \widetilde{\nabla}_t \widetilde{F}_i, F_k \rangle F_k \\
\nabla_t F_t = \Pi(\widetilde{\nabla}_t \widetilde{F}_t) = \frac{1}{|F_t|^2} \langle \widetilde{\nabla}_t \widetilde{F}_t, F_t \rangle F_t + \sum_{k=1}^{n} \frac{1}{|F_k|^2} \langle \widetilde{\nabla}_t \widetilde{F}_t, F_k \rangle F_k
$$
and collecting all the pieces it is now straightforward to obtain the final expressions.

Comment: Geometrically, I think it's reasonable expect $\alpha\left(\frac{\partial}{\partial t},\frac{\partial}{\partial t}\right)=0$. First, it's obvious that $\nabla_{\frac{\partial}{\partial t}}\frac{\partial}{\partial t}=0$. Second, we can see that $\widetilde{\nabla}_{\frac{\partial}{\partial t}}\frac{\partial}{\partial t}=0$ because we can take the geodesic $\gamma(t)=(1+t)f(x)$ in $\mathbb{R}^{n+p+1}$, for which $\gamma'(0)=f(x)=\frac{\partial F}{\partial t}(t,x)$, therefore $\widetilde{\nabla}_{\gamma'}\gamma'=0$.

Comment: But for $\alpha\left(\frac{\partial}{\partial t},\frac{\partial}{\partial x_i}\right)$ and $\alpha\left(\frac{\partial}{\partial x_i},\frac{\partial}{\partial x_j}\right)$, I'm still pretty lost. I only know that in general they can't be all zero, since in that case the immersion would be totally geodesic, which is not necessarily the case.

Comment: @rmdmc89 I completely rewrote the answer trying to make it more clear. See if this helps, please.

Comment: Thank you so much for your patience, Yuri

Comment: Yuri @yurivyatkin I don't understand what $\partial_i F_j$ means. In your notation, $F_j=tf_j$ is a vector field, so what does it mean to differentiate it with respect to $x_i$?

Comment: Also, by  $ \widetilde{\nabla}_i \widetilde{F}_j$ you mean $\widetilde{\nabla}_{\frac{\partial}{\partial y^i}}\widetilde{F}_j$, right?

Comment: @rmdmc89 In order to simplify the notation, I use a lot of identifications between the bundles, which is too verbose to write up. If I do, I will have to reproduce a decent chapter of a textbook. In the nutshell, we refer to this approach as working in the pullback bundles. This is why I drew the picture. In [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2796663/2002) I discuss a similar issue. See, if that helps. Also, notice that I use a very special choice of $y$-coordinates.

Comment: From my experience in math, all identifications are confusing, until the moment they seem totally obvious (then you realize they're useful). In this case, I understand why you chose the $y$ coordinates like you did, but I just want to make sure I'm interpreting the expression $\widetilde{\nabla}_i \widetilde{F}_j=\partial_i F_j$ correctly

Comment: Right now, I'm thinking $\widetilde{\nabla}_i\widetilde{F}_j$ means $\widetilde{\nabla}_{\widetilde{F}_i}\widetilde{F}_j$ and $\partial_iF_j$ means $\left(\frac{\partial f_j^1}{\partial x_i},...., \frac{\partial f_j^{n+p+1}}{\partial x_i}\right)$ (since $F_j=(f_j^1,...,f_j^{n+p+1})$).

Comment: Again, thanks for your patience, I know it must be easier to know it than to explain it (specially to someone who's lost)

Comment: @rmdmc89 Thanks for your curiosity :) Unfortunately, I don't have much time for these calculations and writing. Try to think a little more about the pullback bundles and the identifications therein. A very thorough treatment of this technique (with the pullbacks in disguise) is given in "[A Course in Differential Geometry](https://books.google.co.nz/books)" by W. Klingenberg. It would be very illuminating if you could apply the calculations from my answer to a concrete example, say a standard or elliptic cone in $\mathbb{R}^3$, or to a plane intersecting the sphere.